# Raspberry Pi Space Recovery

Tags: storage

I have recently purchased a Raspberry Pi. I am wondering how I can manage the storage so that my Raspberry Pi (model B 2) will not eventually become cluttered with all sorts of packages and files that I'll download over time.

I don't want to be deleting files that are a part of the Raspberry Pi and/or Raspbian, but for files that I have added on my own, I am wondering if there is a clean, easy system for managing or deleting them.

In addition, is there a simple way to manage the files so that I could pretty much go back to strictly the Raspbian software as the day I opened it, and not when bits and pieces of downloaded software fills its system?

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian has a package manager built into the OS. It's called "apt-get". You can install software by typing `sudo apt-get install {package name here}`.  Likewise, you can delete the software by typing `sudo apt-get remove {package name here`. If you really want to be sure to remove everything the package came with, including configuration files the `purge` option will do that as well.

Once your operating system is installed, and you're happy with how it's configured, you can image it. Remove the SD card from your RPi (turn it off first!) and image it. Later, if you break something, you can simply rewrite that image to the card and it's just like it was the day you imaged it.

Comment: <hairsplitting>Wouldn't it more accurate to say that "Raspbian comes with a package manager `dpkg` application which has a number of different commands beginning with that name"; and some *easier-to-use* front-ends like `apt-get` and `aptitude` that tell it what to do whilst making the process easier and simpler for the user?</hairsplitting>

Comment: Thank you for your time, these are very good suggestions